# Command line: Map network drive

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

How do I write a command line in a .bat or .cmd that maps a network drive? I want the script to first check if the drive-letter is mapped, and if it is delete it and then map the drive.

I only have the mapping-command right now. Please help me fill in the blanks:

```
REM Check if drive exists, if it does, delete it

@echo off

net use q: /persistent:yes \\localhost\C$\MyFolder

pause
```

Are there any of the parameters wrong? Any that should be added?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test for the existence of a drive or folder by testing if the special file "nul" exists in it, i.e.

`REM Test if drive exists`

`IF EXISTS Q:\NUL GOTO Unmap`

`GOTO Continue`

`:Unmap`

`NET USE Q: /DELETE`

`:Continue`

`NET USE Q: /persistent:yes \\localhost\C$\MyFolder`

Of course, since you are going to delete it anyway, you could simply delete it and not bother checking for existence first.

Comment: Great answer thanks... could you just adjust the script to match my example's directory and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this command to delete the mapping (no check required):

```
net use q: /d
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother checking for it, just use "net use q: /delete", which deletes it if it exists otherwise it just return an error.

If you then run the script silently using a bit of vb, the error message won't be displayed (nor will the dos window).

Answer (score 0):

Delete drive X: with error messages suppressed:

```
net use X: /DELETE 2> nul
```

Delete drive X: with both success and error messages suppressed:

```
net use X: /DELETE > nul 2>&1
```