# Is there a way to create a new shared drive through PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I create a new shared drive with the provided credentials on the computer that is running the script?

Is there a PowerShell cmdlet that does that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by shared driver. Do you mean shared drive?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, shared drive. Sorry it's a typo...

Comment: And now: Do you mean to create a public share or how to map a public share to a drive letter?

Comment: Sorry :/ I am asking how to map a public share to a drive letter.

Comment: @mailq Why isn't this a real question?

Comment: Because it needed at least two comments of _you_ to explain what you asked. Still has wrong tags. Is that a good question then? And now it is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/13576/command-line-map-network-drive. And even this is off-topic.

Comment: @maliq why is this offtopic? This is not a programming question. It has everything to do with maintaining a server. Also, I asked how to do it in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Just use "net use" inside your powershell scripts:

> new use z: \\server\share /user:domain\username password

Answer (score 2):

This powershell function should work:

```
Function NEW-SHARE ($Foldername, $Sharename) { 
   # Test for existence of folder, if not there then create it 
   # 
   IF (!(TEST-PATH $Foldername)) { 
       NEW-ITEM $Foldername -type Directory } 
   # Create Share but check to make sure it isn’t already there 
   # 
   If (!(GET-WMIOBJECT Win32_Share -filter “name=$Sharename”) { 
       $Shares.Create($Foldername,$Sharename,0)} 
}
```

The following article on technet provides more information:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/16/how-to-use-powershell-to-create-shared-folders-in-windows-7.aspx